# i am trying to install Ubuntu 13.04 amd-64 desktop on my pc with dual boot..,

Tags: dual-boot, wubi

i am trying to install Ubuntu 13.04 amd-64 desktop on my pc with dual boot.., I don't know how to make it as bootable that Ubuntu 13.04 Iso., So i am trying to install that one by using wubi installer. Then it shows me an error message like "couldn't retrive the disk image files", and it was not at all installing. Will any one have any idea about this.

Comment: The [13.04](http://releases.ubuntu.com/13.04/) `wubi.exe` doesn't use disk images anymore. Where did you get it from? Also, please add a pastebin link to your wubi log file. As it currently stands, your question does not have enough information for us to provide assistance.

Comment: i get it from Ubuntu site it self. and i am using wubi.exe and i faced that problem.., it shows me like "Couldn't retrive the disk image files" and warning message as "please refer "C:\users\..\Appdata\local\wubi-275.log""

Comment: rev275 is really old and broken. The latest 13.04 is rev279. Also what does the log say? And are you asking how to install Wubi or how to install from USB because those are two separate questions? Please edit your question to indicate which it is.

Comment: yeah i think it is 279 really., i mistaken. and i have an .iso file of Ubuntu 13.04 and i burned it into a dvd as bootable but unfortunately it wouldn't work and i am also tried live USB.., it is also not working and what should i do now.

Comment: Also refer to [www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop), particularly the bits on [how to burn a DVD](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/burn-a-dvd-on-windows), [how to create a bootable USB stick](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows), and [how to check the md5sum of the Ubuntu ISO](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HowToMD5SUM)

Comment: yeah i refer that log and it shows me error message like.,Couldn't retrive the required disk image files. So finally i wouldn't install that Ubuntu 13.04 in my laptop at all. I tried 12.10 for AMD-64bit also but it is not possible to install..., will you have any idea about this

Answer (score 0):

You need to record the iso (a DVD image) to a blank DVD using your Windows DVD recording software.

Then you put it in your DVD player and boot from the DVD. How to do this depends on your computer BIOS settings. On some computers you can press F12 or some other function key to get a boot device menu where you can choose the DVD drive. When you boot does it show you a message like **F12 Boot menu** or something of the sort?

On others PC's you'll have to enter BIOS settings (see what shows on screen immediately after you turn your computer on). Find the boot order settings and make sure the DVD drive is before the hard disk. Save settings and continue.

Since you seem inexperienced, please make sure you do a backup on an external drive of all important things on your PC just in case you get it wrong.

If in doubt what options to choose **ask** before continuing.

Comment: nice answer Mr.To Do , But i know how to change boot priority from bios. And i have a DVD image of that Ubuntu 13.04(.Iso file), and i already tried to burn that Iso into a dvd, but it doesn't boot( I already changed my bios to "boot from cd/dvd" option., All i have to know is how to make that .Iso file bootable and how to install Ubuntu 13.04 Ubuntu in my laptop

Comment: What program are you using to burn the iso? Normally, there's nothing you need to do to make the DVD bootable. Just burning the iso produces a bootable DVD.

Comment: sorry Mr.ToDo it never going to booted after burning that iso.., so that's why i used to make that iso as bootable by using PowerIso software..,